# Data intersection yes or no in google Sheets: Looking for ANY of the list items in a defined string (which is also the result of an array formula)

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

We have the following situation.

- We have 1 cell to show the result of a determination in.
- We have 1 cell with data to check for (String, but assume result of array formula concatenated so can use the string or the array)
- And 1 list of items to check against (range reference)

Said otherwise:
The resulting cell should loop through all the items in `LIST OF FRUITS`. If ANY of the fruits is found in the string (or the array before we join it to string) in `CELL TO CHECK` then print "Found" - or if easier print the list item that was found.

And said even more basic: how do we easily determine an intersect between two collections (one of which is the result of an array formula) the other a range reference.

**Question**: Is this possible and if so then how?

```
TEST A (Found)
RESULT CELL          CELL TO CHECK
Found!               mangoes, apples

TEST B (Not found)
RESULT CELL          CELL TO CHECK
-                    Pineapple


LIST OF FRUITS
Apples
Pears
Bananas
Mangoes
```

[image]

Comment: List<string> yourList.forEach(x => yourString.contains(x) ? true : false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B1:B), 
 LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D:D))), "found!", "-")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks this helps. Forgot to say LIST OF FRUITS is an array (retrieved via arrayformula so in array form) and also CELSS to CHECK is an array (range reference). So I am trying to determine: do two collection circles overlap yes or no.

Comment: the answer does exactly that. can you share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output?